# Print line and position of a substring in the line

Tags: string, file, rust, pattern-matching

I am trying a simple program where, given a substring, I read from a text file, line by line and if a substring matches a string in the line, I print the position of the string in the line and the line itself. I am able to do the former part, but not the printing the line.

The code is as shown:

```rust
use std::{
    fs::{self, File},
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
};


fn read_file_line(filepath: &String) -> BufReader<File> {
    let data: File = File::open(filepath).unwrap();
    let buffer: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(data);

    buffer
}


fn main() {
    let filepath: String = "src/poem.txt".to_string();

    // Printing line by line
    let filecontents: BufReader<File> = read_file_line(&filepath);

    let search_phrase: String = "article".to_string();   // word to search is "article"
    for line in filecontents.lines() {
        let index = line.unwrap().find(&search_phrase.trim());

        match index {
            Some(t) => println!("Found at position {t}"),   // how to print the line also here?
            None => (),
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to do `Some(t) => println!("Found at position {:?} of the line {:?}", t, line),`, it is an error `Result<String, std::io::Error> cannot be formatted with the default formatter.` Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Extract `line.unwrap()` to a variable (you can call it `line`) and use it.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to print the contents of the line, or the line number?

Answer (score 1):

You can unwrap `line` into a variable, which you can use twice. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f3e31ed9cf52f9380bc9c342f51b4b4)

```rs
let line: String = line.unwrap();
let index = line.find(&search_phrase.trim());
match index {
    Some(t) => {
        println!("Found at position {t}");
        println!("Line: {}", line);
    },
    None => (),
}
```